# Предложение, которое читается одинаково в обоих направлениях (слева направо и наоборот), при этом игнорируя регистр, пробелы и знаки препинания

Tags: javascript

```
function isWerewolf(target) {
  let direct = '';
  let reverced = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < target.length; i++ ){
    let add = target.replace(/[^a-zа-яё]/gi, '');
      direct += add;
      reverced += add;

      let direct1 = direct.toLowerCase();
      let reverced1 = reverced.toLocaleLowerCase();  

      if(direct1 === reverced1){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  }
}
```

Не пойму как мне добавлять текущий элемент в reversed в конец строки, так что бы он стазу стал перевёртышем. А потом уже проводить сравнение.

Comment: не пойму как мне добавлять текущий елемент в reversed  в конец строки, так что бы он стразу стал перевёртышем. А потом уже проводить сравнениие

Comment: что такое target? строка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм очень прост:

1. Оставляем в строке только буквы и цифры
2. Делим строку посимвольно
3. Разворачиваем
4. Проходимся по получившемуся массиву и смотрим совпадает ли каждый символ в нижнем регистре с символом в строке

```js
const isWerewolf = (str) => {
  const newStr = str.replace(/[^\wа-яё]+/gi, '').toLowerCase();
  
  return newStr.split('').reverse().every((x, i) => x === newStr[i]);
}

console.log(isWerewolf('abBA'));
console.log(isWerewolf('abBAc'));
console.log(isWerewolf('abcdeffedcba!'));
console.log(isWerewolf('абвгдеё ЁЕДГВБА!'));
```

P.S. Надо понимать что в развёрнутом массиве 0-ой элемент - это послдений элемент в строке, 1-ый - это предпоследний элемент и т.д. Потому, когда мы сравниваем 0-ой элменет в развёрнутом массиве с 0-ым элементом в строке, мы сравниваем 0-ой и последний элемент в строке

Comment: Один момент: \w не воспринимает кириллицу

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Ну список всегда можно дополнить)) Спасибо, дополнил)

Comment: Понятное дело. Но ТС, как и я, начнёт проверку с русских палиндромов и расстроится 8)

Answer (score 2):

1. Получаем очищенную от всего лишнего строку в нижнем регистре.
2. Посимвольно сравниваем первую половину строки со второй половиной.

Код не самый компактный, но эффективный:

```js
const isPalindrome = (str) => {
  const cleaned = str.replace(/[^a-zа-яё]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
  let i = ~~(cleaned.length / 2);

  while (--i > 0) {
    if (cleaned[i] !== cleaned[cleaned.length - i - 1]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(
  isPalindrome("Он — верба, но / Она — бревно"),
  isPalindrome("Семиногий пятирук играет в гольф")
);
```

Comment: _сравниваем первую половину строки (от начала) со второй половиной (от конца)._ - судя по коду - наоборот

Comment: @Grundy В двух соснах запутался. Изменил формулировку на более безопасную

Answer (score 2):

Функция будет называться `isPalindrome`, извините. Сперва опустим строке регистр. Затем выделим числа (`\d`) и буквы любых алфавитов на любых языках (`\p{L}`). То что осталось соберём в первую строку. Массив перевернём и соберём во вторую строку. Строки сравним:

```js
const isPalindrome = s => {
    const arr = s.toLowerCase().match(/[\d\p{L}]/gu);
    const s1 = arr.join('');
    arr.reverse();
    const s2 = arr.join('');
    return s1 === s2;
};

[
    'abBA',
    'abBAc',
    'abcdeffedcba!',
    'абвгдеё ЁЕДГВБА!',
    "Он — верба, но / Она — бревно",
    "Семиногий пятирук играет в гольф",
    "А роза упала на лапу Азора.",
    "12321",
    "123"
].forEach(s => console.log(isPalindrome(s), s));
```